# OData: time operations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an ASP.NET WebAPI service that serves json results from to a client JS webapp.

The web client uses OData **(v4)** to filter the requests.
The server side uses a thin Entity Framework layer that just applies the OData filter to the returned dataset.

The data in the DB contains a CallStart field containing date *and* time specific to that item.

I want, on the client, to be able to apply custom filters to *only* the time part of the CallStart field, regardless of the `date` part.

On the client, the user specifies an hour, a minute and an operand.
The allowed operands are `ge, le, eq, ne`

What's the easiest way to achieve this?

The first try was to construct an OData expression:

```
function getODataFilter(hour, minute, operation) {
    return "(hour(CallStart) " + operation + " " + hour 
            + " and minute(CallStart) " + operation + " " + minute)
```

But of course that does not work. If I call, eg, getODataFilter(12, 33, 'ge') and aply that filter, I will get items with `15:34` but not `15:32`, since it only retrieves the items where the `minutes` part is `> 33`.

Now I can see two possibilities, none of which looks very appealing:

1. Create more complicated OData expressions, different for each operation, like:

`(hour(CallStart) eq {hour} and minute(CallStart) ge {minute})
or (hour(CallStart) ge hour)`

2. Add a new computed column in the DB, that just holds the time portion of `CallStart` saved as ...something (like ticks since midnight), convert the client-side time to a numeric value, and just compare simple numbers.

Is there a 3rd, better (simpler?) approach?